# JavaFX TableView: open detail information between rows on click

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm trying to display travel connections in a TableView. So far that works like a charm. Now I'm kinda stuck trying to get details of a connection to be displayed in between table rows. This should happen on selecting a table item.

The problem is, that the details are in a different format than the connections I'm displaying. So I would need to put a panel between two table rows. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a [`TreeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm). But I guess you need the columns that a `TableView` provides. Though, the nodes in the `TreeView` can be modified to look like a table.

Comment: A [`TreeTableView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html) has a tree view structure with the columns a table provides, if that works for what you need. But "the details are in a different format than the connections I'm displaying" suggests this wouldn't be what you needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this would be to create a custom skin for `TableRow` and use a `rowFactory` on the table that returned a `TableRow` with the custom skin installed. However, since skin classes are not public API at the time of writing (note though that they will be in Java 9), this would mean implementing the skin class entirely from scratch (laying out the table cells, etc), which would be pretty difficult.

A less "official" approach, but one that's a little easier, is just to override the various layout methods in the `TableRow` directly, and hook into the superclass implementation.

This works, but feels a little fragile:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithCustomRow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Item>() {
            Node detailsPane ;
            {
                selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                    if (isNowSelected) {
                        getChildren().add(detailsPane);
                    } else {
                        getChildren().remove(detailsPane);
                    }
                    this.requestLayout();
                });
                detailsPane = createDetailsPane(itemProperty());
            }

            @Override
            protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
                if (isSelected()) {
                    return super.computePrefHeight(width)+detailsPane.prefHeight(getWidth());
                } else {
                    return super.computePrefHeight(width);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();
                if (isSelected()) {
                    double width = getWidth();
                    double paneHeight = detailsPane.prefHeight(width);
                    detailsPane.resizeRelocate(0, getHeight()-paneHeight, width, paneHeight);
                } 
            }
        });

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, random.nextInt(100)));
        }
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));

        Scene scene = new Scene(table, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private Node createDetailsPane(ObjectProperty<Item> item) {
        BorderPane detailsPane = new BorderPane();
        Label detailsLabel = new Label();
        VBox labels = new VBox(5, new Label("These are the"), detailsLabel);
        labels.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        labels.setPadding(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 16));
        detailsPane.setCenter(labels);

        Label icon = new Label("Icon");
        icon.setStyle("-fx-background-color: aqua; -fx-text-fill: darkgreen; -fx-font-size:18;");
        BorderPane.setMargin(icon, new Insets(6));
        icon.setMinSize(40, 40);
        detailsPane.setLeft(icon);

        detailsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: -fx-background; -fx-background: skyblue;");

        item.addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (newItem == null) {
                detailsLabel.setText("");
            } else {
                detailsLabel.setText("details for "+newItem.getName());
            }
        });


        return detailsPane ;
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setPrefWidth(150);
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This gives the following:

[image]

Comment: This works brilliantly. Would you mind if I published this solution in a blogpost? It wouldn't be a direct copy but a generalized version of this.

Comment: That's fine; please reference this post though. (BTW, I only tested it very briefly with multiple selection enabled; you might want to test it there too, if you haven't already.)