# JavaFX: Nested Tables

Tags: java, javafx, tree, tableview, treetable

It is possible to create a table that contains other subtables in javafx like in the picture?

[image]

The program in the photo is written in javafx only that it is closed source.

Is there any other external or internal component in java that allows me to create a similar interface?

My problem is the same as this: [JavaFX TableView: open detail information between rows on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110036/javafx-tableview-open-detail-information-between-rows-on-click)
However, i need to load different value in the sub tables for every row. How can i do this?

This is the creation of my sub-tabs.

```
private Node createDetailsPane(ObjectProperty<Model> item) {
    VBox vBox = new VBox();

    ObservableList<Model> dv = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Model> dl = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Model> dp = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    TableView visite = new TableView();
    TableView latte = new TableView();
    TableView parti = new TableView();

    visite.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    latte.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    parti.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    visite.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
    latte.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
    parti.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);

    visite.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    latte.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    parti.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    visite.getColumns().addAll(idVisita, dataVisita, azioniTerapeutiche, descrizioneVisita, incinta, dataPrevistaParto, veterinario);
    latte.getColumns().addAll(idLatte, litri, dataProduzione);
    parti.getColumns().addAll(idParto, dataParto, azioniParticolari);

    visite.setFixedCellSize(25);
    visite.prefHeightProperty().bind(visite.fixedCellSizeProperty().multiply(Bindings.size(visite.getItems()).add(2)));
    visite.minHeightProperty().bind(visite.prefHeightProperty());
    visite.maxHeightProperty().bind(visite.prefHeightProperty());

    latte.setFixedCellSize(25);
    latte.prefHeightProperty().bind(latte.fixedCellSizeProperty().multiply(Bindings.size(latte.getItems()).add(2)));
    latte.minHeightProperty().bind(latte.prefHeightProperty());
    latte.maxHeightProperty().bind(latte.prefHeightProperty());

    parti.setFixedCellSize(25);
    parti.prefHeightProperty().bind(parti.fixedCellSizeProperty().multiply(Bindings.size(parti.getItems()).add(2)));
    parti.minHeightProperty().bind(parti.prefHeightProperty());
    parti.maxHeightProperty().bind(parti.prefHeightProperty());

    parti.setItems(dp);
    latte.setItems(dl);

    String id;
    if(treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().get(treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()-1) != -1) {
        id = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().get(treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()-1).getIdProv();
        try {
            Connection conn = Driver.connection();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/animali?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "admin", "admincs97");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `ID_VISITA`,`DATA_VISITA`,`AZIONI_TERAPEUTICHE`,`DESCRIZIONE_VISITA`,`STATO_VISITA`,`GRAVIDA_DA_GG`,`DATA_PREVISTA_PARTO`,`VETERINARIO` FROM `visite` "
                    + "LEFT JOIN `anagrafe` USING(`ID_PROVVISORIO`, `BOLO`) "
                    + "LEFT JOIN `parti` USING(`ID_PROVVISORIO`, `BOLO`) "
                    + "LEFT JOIN `latte` USING(`ID_PROVVISORIO`, `BOLO`) "
                    +where;
            String temp = "";
            if(where.trim().length() > 0)
                temp += " AND visite.`ID_PROVVISORIO` = '"+id+"'";
            else
                temp = "WHERE visite.`ID_PROVVISORIO` = '"+id+"'";

            sql += temp;

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            if(rs.next())
                do {
                    dv.add(new Model( rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8)));
                    /*rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), 
                    rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20), rs.getString(21), rs.getString(22), rs.getString(23), rs.getString(24), 
                    rs.getString(25), rs.getString(26) */
                } while(rs.next());
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            new FxDialogs().showException("Errore", "Errore nel caricamento dei dati", e);
        }
    }

    visite.setItems(dv);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(visite, latte, parti);
    return vBox ;
}
```

Everything works until I select multiple rows in the main table.

If for example I have two main lines, if I select first the second and then the first the subtables give me back the same value.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX TableView: open detail information between rows on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110036/javafx-tableview-open-detail-information-between-rows-on-click)

Comment: Thanks, but i need to load different value in the subtables for every row.

Comment: @user3866160 why can't you use the same technique to do that? The linked question has different content below every row, depending on what is in that row.

Comment: @James_D It is, in fact, I solved this problem, just that I have another with multiple selection.

Comment: Use the item from the table row (as in the linked question) instead of the selected item.

Comment: If I use item.get().getXX() the subtables returns me the same values

Comment: The problem is that if I use treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().get(treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()-1)
I don't get the last item selected
@James_D